# (UWP) How to build/fill my view based on the response from an HttpClient request?

Tags: c#, view, uwp, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

Good evening,

I am quite new in C# UWP application development (mobile specifically), and I bumped into a feature that I have to implement : getting data from a REST web API and build my view based on the response : when it succeeds, filling the XAML view and when it fails, displaying a "retry" page or something else.

I found some documentation about the [HttpClient class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient) on Microsoft's doc, the [HttpClient sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/HttpClient) on their GitHub repository, and Stephen Cleary's explanations about deadlocks when using asynchronous methods into UI ones. They all treat the HttpClient context well, but I didn't find anything that was treating about XAML data binding with HTTP requests.

I must admit that I am kinda lost in all of these explanations and I couldn't find any documentation that would suit my needs.

Right now, I have custom XAML Page that contains a ListView with a specific bind :

```
<Page
x:Class="windows_app.Views.SheetsListPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:data="using:windows_app.Models"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:behaviors="using:Template10.Behaviors"
xmlns:controls="using:Template10.Controls"
xmlns:Interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid   Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <controls:PageHeader Frame="{x:Bind Frame}" 
                         BackButtonVisibility="Visible"
                         Content="Sheets List"
                         Background="#FF2B2B2B"
                         Foreground="White"
                         IsSticky="True">

        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviors:EllipsisBehavior Visibility="Auto" />
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>

    </controls:PageHeader>

    <ListView   x:Name="SheetsListView"
                ItemsSource="{x:Bind CultureSheets}"
                Margin="5,52,5,0" Padding="5">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:CultureSheet">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image      Width="64" Height="64" Source="{x:Bind CultureImage}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center" Text="{x:Bind Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>

</Grid>
```

From what I understand so far, before displaying the view I should send my HttpRequest, waiting for the response and based on this one, either filling the data or displaying a different page that would notify the user that the request failed, allowing the user to try again. The thing is that I don't really know where in the code I would proceed like this, and also I'm not sure that it would be the best (and proper) way to develop what I intend to do.

Could you lead me to some documentation that I could have missed, treating about this topic, or indicating me what would be the good way to implement it ?

I am using Universal Windows SDK 10.0.14393.0 with the Mobile Extensions.

Comment: There is no need to wait to display the view. The ViewModel will load the data async and while loading set the ViewModel property IsBusy to true (the View can show a busy animation) and when the data is retrieved assign it to the CultureSheets and set IsBusy to false.

Comment: The thing I don't understand is that, in every example I've seen so far, they don't mention any busy indicator or view updates or problems. Am I missing something there ?

Comment: You were asking for a good way to implement it. Have a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/BikeSharing360_MobileApps for a complete example